# Is there a html conditional statement for everything not Outlook?

Tags: html, email

I found a snippet of code that allows me to target clients that have outlook 2007 or higher.

`<!--[if gte mso 9]><![endif]-->`

Is there anyway to target everything but outlook or outlook 2007 & higher? If you're giving an answer please give working code as I've tried

`<!--[if ! mso 9]>`
`<!--[if ! mso]>`
`<!--[if !(mso)]>`

None of the following worked in Gmail with firefox.

Comment: Conditional comments are a Microsoft non-standard (though standards-compliant) implementation, allowing people to directly address flaws in the Microsoft family of html browsers/clients. As such, there's not usually an easy way to target other vendors' products with `!IE` or `!mso` syntax.

Comment: thanks, perhaps you could suggest the logic on how to hide a specific table row from outlook?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!--[if !mso]>-->
  content targeted at non-outlook users goes here...
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: To prevent statements being stripped in outlook.com, change `<!-->` to `<!-- -->` - check my answer for example

Comment: This doesn't work on outlook.com in a browser. Both the outlook content and non outlook content show up at the same time.

Answer (score 24):

To prevent statements being stripped in outlook.com, change `<!-->` to `<!-- -->` -

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    All Except MSO 07-13
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This trick was stripping the content in the gmail app and the android mail app, strangely enough ...

Comment: This 'solution' was described in more detail here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7544/outlookcom-problems-with-conditional-comments-in-the-body/

Answer (score 7):

Super late response, but hopefully this will help someone. This worked for me:

```
<!--[if !gte mso 9]><!---->
<p>I'm not Outlook 2007/2010.</p>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Edit: Answered above, but extra tags on the IF statement are to hide the tags from being revealed in IE7/8.

Answer (score 3):

That's is a solution:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
content without use in IE or Outlook
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I think so you can first resolve in IE, Outlook and denied with this for putting the elementss for all differents clients for email  without Outlook.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft defines a way to write conditional HTML that will be revealed in those clients that don't understand Microsoft's proprietary "conditional comments":

`<![if !mso]>  HTML meant for non-Outlook clients  <![endif]>`

They call it a "downlevel-revealed conditional comment", though it's not actually a comment at all, since comments start with `<!--`.  Microsoft Office and Internet Explorer process the conditional statement (`!mso` evaluates false in Outlook), while other clients ignore the unrecognized tags.  See [Microsoft's documentation on conditional comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v=vs.85)).

Answer (score -1):

Conditionals in comments like `<!--[if gte mso 9]...` is IE specific. Will not work in other browsers.

Comment: This is more like a comment…

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you have to use it. Instead it is, `for everything except Outlook` - normal routine, `for Outlook` - do specific. Not the other way around like you're trying to do.

Comment: That's true but this type of comment has its uses. Sometimes we _do_ need to force Outlook to turn a blind eye on certain code, not other way around. For example, I discovered that compatibility tag caused trouble on Outlook: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`, I had to comment it out with "not-Outlook" comment. But in general, for template code, you're right.